# Laravel composer install hangs on “Installing dependencies”

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php, freeze

I cloned project written by laravel from bitbucket to my localhost. Now I want to install composer.

When I try to run `composer install` , installation hangs at:

`Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)`

Comment: That step can take a little while, what do you mean with "Hanging"?

Comment: I know this can take a little but at this case take more and stop at this step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing using the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel
```

It might take a little while but is definitely more reliable.  If this is hanging you can try installing with the laravel.phar which can be found at http://laravel.com/laravel.phar

Comment: It's create new project but I wanna install composer to project cloned from bitbucket.

Comment: Ahh... sorry, I thought it was a fresh installation of Laravel.  What I posted is correct for that use.  It was taken directly from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel).

Comment: Have you tried running `composer update` instead of `composer install`?  Is this a private repo on bitbucket or is it publicly accessible?

Comment: I tried running `composer update` but errors appeared.This is a private repo

Comment: `Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.5`

Comment: Ahhh. Do you mind showing what you have listed in your require section of your composer.json file?

Comment: `"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
  "intervention/image": "dev-master",
  "ceesvanegmond/minify": "dev-master",
  "fbf/laravel-youtube": "dev-master"
 }`

Comment: Aha!  The issue is with `fbf/laravel-youtube` no longer supports v. 4.0 of laravel. You should also add `"google/apiclient": "dev-master"` to your `composer.json` as `fbf/laravel-youtube` requires it.  Once you have added that and changed `"laravel/framework": "4.0.*"` to `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"` it should work.  You should also follow [this guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1) once you have updated.